# How to populate int array dynamiclly by a given range?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to know how to populate an array dynamically given a start point and end point ?  Assuming it's possible ?

my current way (hard coding ints)

```
int xValues[] = {340,347,348,349,352,355,359,364,369,376,383,392,400,410,421,431,443,455,467,480,492,505,519,532,545,559,572,585,599,612,625,637,648,658,667,675,681,686,690,693,696,697,698,700};  
for (int i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++) 
{  

    x=xValues[i];
```

Desired way

```
int xValues[] = Range(340, 700);  // if possible unit of increment 1 or 10
```

Thank you and happy coding.

Comment: You should look into `Random` class and the `nextInt()` method

Comment: its is simple, find indexes of your starting and ending values, then you need to get subarray from your arrays (ie by using `Arrays.copyOfRange` or  `System.arraycopy`) and you have your array

Comment: @LittleChild - Thanks for the help. I will look into Arrays.copyOfRange and nextInt()  Not sure where all the hate is coming from.  I just wanted to know if it's possible ?  I would have been happy with an answer of "Yes it's possible".  But thanks for helping.   I will delete the question as soon as possible.

Comment: @AhabLives Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a code that generates random numbers between the given range, the below code is for you

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Random;
 public class Insert {
static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String [] args){
 Random rand=new Random();
 int max,min;
 System.out.println("enter the maximum number");
 max=input.nextInt();
 System.out.println("enter the minimum number");
 min=input.nextInt();
 int range=max-min+1;
 int arr[]=new int[100];
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
      int random=rand.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
      arr[i]=random;  
  }

 for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
      System.out.println(arr[i]);

  }


 }
```

Comment: I think you should not answer questions like this because it will encourage uninformed users to post more.

Comment: yes, may be the seniors like you will get angry  and downvote the persons like me, so the cost of answering this question is -4 reputation ... hats off stack overflow

Comment: I'm not anywhere near being a senior but I've read all the guidelines and I know what I should not ask here. You can either understand it and hire someone to write code for you or your questions will get closed. I'm not angry either I just don't like the noise on this site which is caused by users who does not care to read the FAQ. Don't take it personally. I was in your shoes as well. I asked off topic questions until I realized that I can either accept it or go somewhere else.

Comment: how can you say **this should not be asked here**,there is not any rule that a person should know everything ,the persons who does not know this , might know many other,or may be he did not know "random number generation" in this case @AdamArold

Comment: he asked us to write code for him. He does not have a question. He even said "happy coding" for our programming task...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=votes&pagesize=15
i  think many of these are pretty much like above, and are **dumb** if you ask me,is not that noise? and "happy coding" may be just a greeting, may be he is non native english speaker

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35928/discussion-between-vamsi-and-adam-arold)

Comment: Wow, I am truly sorry for causing so much anger. I thought "happy coding" meant "may you have a happy life in coding"....I will never use the term again.

Comment: dude at least gimme a **tick mark** for my answer, i already lost some reputation cuz of you @AhabLives